# Firebase in-app message center/inbox design

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to build an in-app inbox (a.k.a. message center) as a central place to store messages to my app's users. Think one-way email notifications rather than user-user chat. This is the sort of thing I have in mind (taken from the [Victoria Secret app](http://www.mobilecommercedaily.com/victorias-secret-makes-message-center-focus-of-new-app-revamp)):

[image: VS app]

Urban Airship [have a product](https://www.urbanairship.com/products/engage/message-center) which does what I'm after and Intercom.io comes close (although it's focussed more on chat rather than asyncronous email style messages). However, I'm using Firebase elsewhere in my app so I thought it makes sense to use the same SDK for the in-app inbox too rather than introduce another 3rd party.

My question is: does anyone know whether the following logic makes sense (I'm developing on iOS with Swift first)?

1. Create a tableView as the "inbox"
2. Use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM) to send a payload to the app including message title, body etc
3. Add a method to the app to receive the payload and update the tableView's data source

Ideally, I'd like to trigger a notification (+ badge update) if the app's in the background when the message is received and an in-app notification when the app's in the foreground. I'm assuming I can do this with FCM/[Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/).

Has anyone created this sort of thing in the past or have any suggested pitfalls I should be aware of?